# Google Analytics find average session duration for only new users

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to get the average session duration for new users?  For example, if an application has a very poor start screen but awesome once you're able to use it, the average session duration would be high, but the average session duration for new users would be low.  Is there a way to figure this out?

Comment: I have answered your question below, remember to marked as resolved if the answer is satisfactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go to the Audience Report > Behavior> **New vs Returning**

Within that report you will find the Avg. Session duration.

You can leverage the use of **Segments**, click on **+Add Segment** and select the "New User Segment" you will add another line to the chart, play with the metrics and have fun.

[image]